# Exporting sharp corners in Bézier curves to pdf

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format, splines

I'm a bit baffled by this. I have a number of arrows in a series of diagrams, and I'm defining the arrowheads using Bézier curves such as

```
test =  Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[8], 
   BezierCurve[
    3 {{-1, -0.5}, {-0.7, -0.2}, {-0.3, -0.07}, {0, 0}, {-0.3, 
       0.07}, {-0.7, 0.2}, {-1, 0.5}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 1}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

I would then like to export these diagrams, ideally to pdf since the display will be large and I want a vector version to use with pdflatex. However, exporting to pdf results in a blunt arrow:

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.pdf", test]
```

[image]

This is surprising because (i) the front end displays this with a sharp kink, and (ii) exporting to png does the same.

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.png", test]
```

[image]

Is there a way to get a sharp kink when exporting to pdf?

Comment: I heavily suspect this might be OS dependent. Also what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: This is v10.4.0 on Ubuntu 15.10. I don't have access to any other OSs, though.

Comment: On Windows (with M- 10.4) the arrow is blunted in the front end

Comment: @chuy Thanks. That probably means I'm banking on buggy behaviour, then =|.

Comment: my thinking is the blunt end is the mathematically correct form.  To achieve that corner in eps/pdf you need to render two separate curves that are joined so that the behavior is controlled by `linejoin` . Sorry I don't know off hand how to do that from within mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MMA 10.3 on OSX 10.10.5 I get the same behaviour as @chuy - blunt on the front end and both export formats.

I think the implementation is kind of buggy as one might expect the option `JoinForm -> "Miter"` to solve the problem, however it changes nothing.

However, using the additional option `JoinForm -> {"Miter",d}` does create the desired behaviour for sufficiently high `d` (which curiously can't be `inf`...):

```
test = Graphics[{
   AbsoluteThickness[8],
   JoinForm[{"Miter", 100}], 
   BezierCurve[3 {{-1, -0.5}, {-0.7, -0.2}, {-0.3, -0.07}, {0, 0}, {-0.3, 0.07}, {-0.7, 0.2}, {-1, 0.5}}]
}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 1}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

Give for the front-end, PDF, and PNG

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm.